# How to add a custom font this activity?

Tags: android, fonts

I have a problem with this activity file I tried to modify I mean to add a custom font this TextView. I tried many code, it doesn't work for me. hope I will find the solution by this Question.

this my activty code:

```
private ArrayList<SongInfo> items;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<ViewHolder> listHolder = new ArrayList<ListRingtonesAdapter.ViewHolder>();
private int curPosition = 0;
private RingtonesSharedPreferences pref;
private boolean inRingtones;

static final String TAG = "LOG";

private static final int DEFAULT_RINGTONE = 1;
private static final int ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT = 2;
private static final int DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION = 3;
private static final int DEFAULT_ALARM = 4;
private static final int DELETE_RINGTONE = 5;



public static final String ALARM_PATH = "/media/audio/alarms/";
public static final String ALARM_TYPE = "Alarm";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_PATH = "/media/audio/notifications/";
public static final String NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "Notification";
public static final String RINGTONE_PATH = "/media/audio/ringtones/";
public static final String RINGTONE_TYPE = "Ringtone";


public ListRingtonesAdapter(Context context, int viewResourceId,
        ArrayList<SongInfo> objects, boolean inRingtones) {
    super(context, viewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.items = objects;
    this.pref = new RingtonesSharedPreferences(context);
    this.inRingtones = inRingtones;
    if(Main.mp.isPlaying()){
        Main.mp.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ActionItem defRingtone = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_RINGTONE,
            "Default Ringtone", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.icon_ringtone));
    ActionItem assign = new ActionItem(ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT,
            "Contact Ringtone", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.icon_contact));
    ActionItem defNotifi = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION,
            "Default Notification", context.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.icon_notify));
    ActionItem defAlarm = new ActionItem(DEFAULT_ALARM, "Default Alarm",
            context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_alarm));


    final QuickAction mQuickAction = new QuickAction(context);

    mQuickAction.addActionItem(defRingtone);
    mQuickAction.addActionItem(assign);
    mQuickAction.addActionItem(defNotifi);
    mQuickAction.addActionItem(defAlarm);


    // setup the action item click listener
    mQuickAction
            .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(QuickAction quickAction, int pos,
                        int actionId) {
                    switch (actionId) {
                    case DEFAULT_RINGTONE:
                        setDefaultRingtone(items.get(curPosition));
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Ringtone set successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case ASSIGN_TO_CONTACT:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                                SelectContactActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position", curPosition);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case DEFAULT_ALARM:
                        setDefaultAlarm(items.get(curPosition));
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Alarm set successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION:
                        setDefaultNotice(items.get(curPosition));
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Notification set successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

    // setup on dismiss listener, set the icon back to normal
    mQuickAction.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
        }
    });

    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.listelement, null);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
        holder.btnFavorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        holder.btnPlayPause = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
    }

    final SongInfo item = items.get(position);
    if (item != null) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.txtName.setText(item.getName());
        if (item.isFavorite()) {
            holder.btnFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite);
        } else {
            holder.btnFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_off);
        }

        if (!item.isPlaying()) {
            holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
        } else {
            holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
        }

        holder.btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
                    Main.mp.stop();
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
                    if(items.get(i) != item)
                        items.get(i).setPlaying(false);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i < listHolder.size(); i++){
                    listHolder.get(i).btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                }

                if (item.isPlaying()) {
                    holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                    item.setPlaying(false);
                    items.get(position).setPlaying(false);
                    if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
                        Main.mp.stop();
                    }

                } else {
                    curPosition = position;
                    playAudio(context, item.getAudioResource());

                    holder.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                    item.setPlaying(true);
                    items.get(position).setPlaying(true);
                }
                for (ViewHolder object : listHolder) {
                    if (object != holder) {
                        object.btnPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.btnFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (item.isFavorite()) {
                    holder.btnFavorite
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_off);
                    item.setFavorite(false);
                    pref.setString(item.getFileName(), false);
                    if (!inRingtones) {
                        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                        broadcast.setAction("REMOVE_SONG");
                        context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                    }

                } else {
                    holder.btnFavorite
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite);
                    item.setFavorite(true);
                    pref.setString(item.getFileName(), true);
                }
            }
        });

        listHolder.add(holder);

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mQuickAction.show(v);
                curPosition = position;
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}

private Object getAssets() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private TextView findViewById(int txtsongname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtName;
    private ImageView btnFavorite;
    private ImageView btnPlayPause;
}

private void playAudio(Context context, int id) {
    if (Main.mp.isPlaying()) {
        Main.mp.stop();
    }
    Main.mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, id);
    Main.mp.setOnCompletionListener(playCompletionListener);
    Main.mp.start();
    onRingtonePlay.onPlay();
}

private OnCompletionListener playCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
            items.get(i).setPlaying(false);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < listHolder.size(); i++){
            listHolder.get(i).btnPlayPause
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
        }
    }
};

private void setRingtone(SongInfo info, boolean ringtone, boolean alarm,
        boolean music, boolean notification) {

    File dir = null;
    String what = null;
    if (ringtone) {
        what = "Ringtones";
    }else if(alarm){
        what = "alarms";
    }else if(notification){
        what = "notifications";
    }else{
        what = "Ringtones";
    }


    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
    } else {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                    .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

    String[] projection = new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION

    };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()+ "\"", null, null);

    String strRingtone = null, strAlarm = null, strNotifi = null, strMusic = null;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        strRingtone = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE));
        strAlarm = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM));
        strNotifi = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION));
        strMusic = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC));
    }

    if (ringtone) {
        if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
            alarm = true;
        if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
            notification = true;
        if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
            music = true;

    } else if (notification) {
        if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
            alarm = true;
        if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
            ringtone = true;
        if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
            music = true;

    } else if (alarm) {
        if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
            notification = true;
        if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
            ringtone = true;
        if ((strMusic != null) && (strMusic.equals("1")))
            music = true;

    } else if (music) {
        if ((strNotifi != null) && (strNotifi.equals("1")))
            notification = true;
        if ((strRingtone != null) && (strRingtone.equals("1")))
            ringtone = true;
        if ((strAlarm != null) && (strAlarm.equals("1")))
            alarm = true;
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    if (ringtone) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, ringtone);
    } else if (notification) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    } else if (alarm) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, alarm);
    } else if (music) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, music);
    }

    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

    int type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALL;
    if (ringtone)
        type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE;
    if (alarm)
        type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM;
    if (notification)
        type = RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION;

    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, newUri);
}

private void setDefaultRingtone(SongInfo info) {

    File dir = null;
    String what = "Ringtones";
    Uri newUri = null;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    boolean isRingTone = false;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
    } else {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                    .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE
            };

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
    if (cursor!=null) {
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
            if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                isRingTone = true;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    if (isRingTone) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
    }else{
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
    }
}

private void setDefaultAlarm(SongInfo info) {

    File dir = null;
    String what = "alarms";
    Uri newUri = null;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    boolean isRingTone = false;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
    } else {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                    .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM
            };

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
    if (cursor!=null) {
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
            if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                isRingTone = true;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    if (isRingTone) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
    }else{
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
    }
}

private void setDefaultNotice(SongInfo info) {

    File dir = null;
    String what = "notifications";
    Uri newUri = null;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    boolean isRingTone = false;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),what);
    } else {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = context.getResources()
                    .openRawResource(info.getAudioResource());

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION
            };

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA+" = '"+file.getAbsolutePath()+"'",null, null);
    if (cursor!=null) {
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        int ringtoneColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String audioFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
            if (cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn)!=null && cursor.getString(ringtoneColumn).equals("1")) {
                Uri hasUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(audioFilePath);
                newUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(hasUri, cursor.getString(idColumn));
                isRingTone = true;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    if (isRingTone) {
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
    }else{
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, info.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, file.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
    }
}

private void deleteRingtone(SongInfo info) {
    File dir = null;
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Ringtones");
    } else {
        dir = context.getCacheDir();
    }

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "dir:"+dir.getPath());

    File file = new File(dir, info.getFileName());
    Log.d(TAG, "file name:"+info.getFileName());

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file
            .getAbsolutePath());

    context.getContentResolver().delete(
            uri,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = \"" + file.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "\"", null);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
}

OnRingtonePlay onRingtonePlay;
/**
 * @param onRingtonePlay the onRingtonePlay to set
 */
public void setOnRingtonePlay(OnRingtonePlay onRingtonePlay) {
    this.onRingtonePlay = onRingtonePlay;
}
interface OnRingtonePlay{
    public void onPlay();
}
}
```

> i Want to add a font to this "textView"
>   holder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);

I tried this but it doesnt work for me:

```
    // give the font path
        String fontPath = "font/myfont.otf";
        TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
        // get the font face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset((AssetManager) getAssets(), fontPath);
        // Apply the font
        txtName.setTypeface(tf);
        // holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
```

and thank you very Much :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i add a a custom font,check what did you missed

1.Create an assets folder

[image]

2. Add a separate folder/directory for fonts and name it as fonts

[image]

3.Add the fonts to that folder

[image]

4.Now i can set my font , this is how i do it

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Xcelsion.ttf");  //    if you are inside a fragment use -> getActivity().getAssets()    .....check your path is correct 
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);  // set that font to the textview you want
```

Note : If you are in other Class that accept your Activitie's context use `yourContextThatYouGot.getAssets()` ,if you are in a fragment use `getActivity().getAssets()` instead of `getAssets()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which context i will use here "     if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.listelement, null);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSongName);
        holder.btnFavorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorite);
        holder.btnPlayPause = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
    }

Comment: see `ListRingtonesAdapter` where do you call this from and how you call it? it has that param `context` keep a global Context mContext in that class and assign it inside  `ListRingtonesAdapter` when it gets called inside it `this.mContext = context` then you have the value mContext that you can use mContext .getAssets()